# how to list users and the groups they are part of in office 365 powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, office365

i need a script please  to export users in office 365 and the groups they are part of and not the other  way around. can anyone help please. all answers i found were to export distribution groups and their members.

i tried using the below but i dont know how to select group names.

`get-mailbox | ? {$_.PrimarySMTPAddress -like "*domain.com"} | Select DisplayName,Alias,PrimarySMTPAddress'`

and i tried this too

`get-mailbox | ? {$_.PrimarySMTPAddress -like "*domain.com"} | Sort Name | % { $MbxDirData = $_ ; Get-MailboxStatistics $_ } | Select DisplayName, @{E={ $MbxDirData.Alias };L='Alias'}, @{E={ $MbxDirData.PrimarySMTPAddress };L='PrimarySMTPAddress'}, @{E={ $_.TotalItemSize.Value + $_.TotalDeletedItemSize.Value };L="TotalMailboxSize"}`

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but I think you can use cmdlets [Get-User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-user?view=exchange-ps) and then [Get-Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-group?view=exchange-ps) to retrieve the groups a user is a member of like this:

```
Get-Mailbox | Where-Object {$_.PrimarySMTPAddress -like "*domain.com"} | ForEach-Object {
    $user   = Get-User -Identity $_.DistinguishedName                      
    $groups = Get-Group | Where-Object {$_.Members -contains $User}
    $_ | Select-Object DisplayName, Alias, PrimarySMTPAddress,
                       @{Name = 'Groups' ; Expression = {$groups.Name -join '; '}}
} | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\O365UserGroups.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

The above concatenates the groups with a semi-colon in one single field of the CSV, but if you would rather have output where there is one line for each group, you can do:

```
Get-Mailbox | Where-Object {$_.PrimarySMTPAddress -like "*domain.com"} | ForEach-Object {
    $user   = Get-User -Identity $_.DistinguishedName                      
    $groups = Get-Group | Where-Object {$_.Members -contains $User}
    # output a data row for each group in the collection
    foreach ($group in $groups) {
        $_ | Select-Object DisplayName, Alias, PrimarySMTPAddress,
                       @{Name = 'Groups' ; Expression = {$group.Name}}
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\O365UserGroups.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works great, but 2 things please it takes so much time and still exporting and the final thing its giving group names not group emails and finally can we have only distribution lists not all internal groups in the exported file? please

Comment: @TeeJay You could try `$groups = Get-Group | Where-Object {$_.RecipientType -like '*DistributionGroup' -and $_.Members -contains $User}` to filter distributionlists only.

Comment: no it is not working it is giving empty groups

Answer (score 1):

We can list all the office 365 groups by using the PowerShell cmdlet **[Get-UnifiedGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-unifiedgroup?view=exchange-ps)** and its group members by **[Get-UnifiedGroupLinks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-unifiedgrouplinks?view=exchange-ps)** cmdlet .

You can use the below PowerShell script  ,which will Export All Office 365 Group Members to csv. We have tested this  in our local environment which is working fine.

```
$Groups = Get-UnifiedGroup -ResultSize Unlimited
$Groups | ForEach-Object {
$group = $_
Get-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity $group.Name -LinkType Members -ResultSize Unlimited | ForEach-Object {
      New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
       Group = $group.DisplayName
       Member = $_.Name
       EmailAddress = $_.PrimarySMTPAddress
       RecipientType= $_.RecipientType
}}} | Export-CSV "C:\Office365GroupMembers.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

**Here is the sample output screenshot for reference :**

[image]

**Note:**
Get-UnifiedGroup cmdlet is available only in the cloud-based service.

For more Information you refer [this](https://morgantechspace.com/2016/06/list-office-365-group-members-using-powershell.html#:%7E:text=We%20can%20list%20all%20the%20office%20365%20groups,following%20command%20lists%20all%20the%20office%20365%20groups.) blog post & also if you faces any issues while executing `Get-unifiedGroup` cmdlet you refer [this](https://morgantechspace.com/2018/07/the-term-get-unifiedgroup-is-not-recognized-as-cmdlet.html#:%7E:text=Get-UnifiedGroup%20:%20The%20term%20%27Get-UnifiedGroup%27%20is%20not%20recognized,that%20the%20path%20is%20correct%20and%20try%20again.) .

Comment: Thank you so much for your help but i just need the export to be emails and the groups they belong too, i don't want to export groups.